# How to Validate TextEdit to accept Website address,Phone,Email formats only in WPF from .cs file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I have a TextEdit on form. which contains website address Text Field, Phone(US), email. I want to validate all these from .cs file. Please any one can help me?

WPF Markup:

```
<dxe:TextEdit x:Name="txtEmpFacebook" TabIndex="25" MaxLength="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="606,0,0,3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="88" LostFocus="txtEmpFacebook_LostFocus"/>

<Label x:Name="lblEmpFacebookError" Content="*" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="985,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="13.467,-0.231" Grid.Row="1"/>

protected bool ValidateAllContactDetails()
        {
            bool isfocused = false;
            bool isValid = true;
            //Validate Contact First Name
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmpFirstName.Text))
            {
                isValid = false;
                lblEmpFirstNameError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                if (!isfocused)
                {
                    isfocused = true;
                    txtEmpFirstName.Focus();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblEmpFirstNameError.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
}
```

This works fine for Empty Text and displays Error. but now want to Validate the Website URL Format,Phone (US) format, Email Format in existing code. 
Any one can help me?
Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

for Url Validation use the regular expression, below--->

```
^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&%\$#_]*)?$
```

for phone(US)--->

```
/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
```

& FOR email validation--->

```
 ^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$
```

and how to use these regular expression, have look here--->

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx

Comment: Thans for replying! for URL i need the following format: http://www.domain.com/page.ext or www.domain.com/page or www.domain.co.in

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to get the validating right for email address and phone number is complicated and cannot be handled by few lines of code. Better reuse WPF controls which provide these functionality.

By the way, not just validation is helpful, but also not letting the user make mistakes when entering the data, i.e. controlling which keys the user can press.

The code for all this functionality is too big to be posted here, but you can find TextBoxes validating Email and Phone numbers at:
  [github.com/PeterHuberSg/WpfWindowsLib](https://github.com/PeterHuberSg/WpfWindowsLib)

Here are 2 links describing what one needs to consider when doing this kind of validation:
[Codeproject: Email-Address-Validation-Explained-in-Detail](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5260174/Email-Address-Validation-Explained-in-Detail-Code)
[Codeporject: Base-WPF-Window-Functionality-for-Data-Entry](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5257393/Base-WPF-Window-Functionality-for-Data-Entry)